# Git error when trying to git init or any other command

Tags: git

fatal: bad numeric config value 'c:.config\jgit\config' for 'GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM': invalid unit

Comment: well, what does that file contain

Answer (score 1):

You have set the `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` environment variable to something Git does not recognize as a valid value.

```
$ GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM='c:.config\jgit\config' git
fatal: bad numeric config value 'c:.config\jgit\config' for 'GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM': invalid unit
```

GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM does not specify where to get the config file. It says whether or not Git should use the system config file in `/etc/config`.

> **GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM**
>
> Whether to skip reading settings from the system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
> file. This environment variable can be used along with $HOME and
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME to create a predictable environment for a picky script, or you
> can set it temporarily to avoid using a buggy /etc/gitconfig file while waiting
> for someone with sufficient permissions to fix it.

So it's going to be true of false or 0 or 1.